# How to switch off "you can use new shorter array creation syntax" hint in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2?

Tags: linux, php, netbeans, array

I use NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 on Linux Mint.
I searched through the options few times, but I can never find the option to switch this hint off in there.

I know well about the new syntax in PHP, but I don't want to see this hint in all the files that use array() syntax.

Comment: Have you tried browsing **Tools** > **Options** > **Editor** > **Hints** ?

Comment: Yes and it wasn't there, then I switched to PHPStorm.